# How to enable immersive mode on landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-immersive

I'm showing Google Map on my application. I want it to look immersive so I added this line.

```
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
```

There is nothing wrong on portrait mode with this line of code but I want full immersive experience on landscape mode as well. Status bar is not transparent/immersive on landscape mode with only a few devices. It may be because of Android versions. Let me attach screenshot to explain my problem better.

I also added these properties to main theme

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

[image]
[image]

Android Version: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about Android versions. It is all about cutouts some devices have.

See. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout

LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES - Content renders into the cutout area in both portrait and landscape modes.

When I set the property to main theme it works seemlessly

```
 <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
 shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, never -->
 </item>
```